# Printing only letters that are between 2 characters in python

Tags: regex, string, loops, python-3.8

So I need to print only letters that are in between lets say o's so if I input

```
string = "ovdasdaso je ovakvo okovano okej"
```

I need to get "vadasdas" , "vakv", "k", " "

I found this code that starts writing text when it finds o and stops when it finds another one but I dont know how to loop trough it so that it would do that more then once. This is the code:

```
start_marker = end_marker = 'o'
string = "ovdasdaso je ovakvo okovano okej"
start = string.index(start_marker) + len(start_marker)
end = string.index(end_marker, start + 1)
p=string[start:end]

print(string)
```

if you got any shorter solutions that would be great as well but mainly I just need a way to loop trough this one

Comment: The solution you have accepted doesn't give the results you desire according to your question.

Comment: @Nick well it did but if you think you got better solution feel free to post it

Comment: The fourth value in the array in the answer is "van". In your question, the fourth answer is " " (a space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

string = "ovdasdaso je ovakvo okovano okej"
print(re.findall(r"(?<=o)(?! )(.*?)(?=o)", string))
```

Output:

```
['vdasdas', 'vakv', 'k', 'van']
```

---

**regex Explanation:**

- `(?<=o)` Negative lookbehind to assert `o` is behind
- `(?! )` Negative lookahead to assert  (empty space) is not ahead
- `(.*?)` matches anything (non-greedy)
- `(?=o)` Negative lookahead to asserts `o` is ahead